# Web Service Return Type

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans6.7

what are the possible return types for a web service? I am using NetBeans 6.7.1 and working in Java.
I want to make a web service that would return String[]... I made a class of Authorization and I want to add a function in an already made web service. the problem is that it doesnt let me make an operation of return type string.

Any solution, please help!
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xs:complexType name="VoucherType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:requestType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DateRedeemed" type="xs:date"  minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="SerialNumber" type="xs:string"    minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is a simple example.

Just returning the basic types.
Not sure about returning arrays of Strings